# Using Json to check if a column contains certain text

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

So I have this sharepoint list with a (for example) "Date" column, and I want to check if any of the rows contain certain text. For example, in the rows it will either say "The due date for homework is: ", or it will say the "The due date for test is: ". Since a date will be added on to the end, I can't just check the whole string, so I want to check if it just contains a few key words. If it contains homework, turn it green, if it contains test, turn it red. Can I do this with Json? Thanks, let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` and other string functions to work with strings in JSON formatting as described in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Here is an example to change color based on your requirement.
To change background, replace *color* attribute with *background-color*

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, 'homework' )>0, 'Green', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'test' )>0, 'Red', 'black'))",
    "font-size": "1.12em"    
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks, indexof is exactly what I was looking for